# How do you hide sensitive information held in variables on a docker-compose file

Tags: docker-compose, travis-ci, servers

I am fairly new to DevOps. I have managed to build myself a CI/DI pipeline for my [open source project](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Identity).

As soon as I check-in some code into GitHub, Travis CI takes over, it builds a fresh docker image of my code, pushes it to DockerHub, then the `after_success` step within [my `.travis.yml`](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Identity/blob/develop/.travis.yml) connects to my VPS via SSH, and runs a script on there which basically does a `docker-compose down` followed by a `docker-compose pull && docker compose up`.

All seems to be working correctly. But I have an issue with [my `docker-compose.yml`](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Identity/blob/develop/docker-compose.yml). Right now as you can see, it has all my environmental variables. Those are considered secret information. How do I hide them from the `docker-compose.yml` file whilst having everything still working as before?

**UPDATE**

I went and created myself a `variables.env` file in the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml`. Inside the `.env` file, I put my old variables, for example:

```
Database__DefaultConnectionString: "Server=database;Port=5432;Database=bejebeje_identity;User Id=postgres;Password=admin;"
```

But in Travis CI I get the following error:

> environment variable name 'Database__DefaultConnectionString: "Server' may not contains whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use environment variables on your host that are read by your `docker-compose.yml` file.  There are a couple ways to accomplish this.  One way is to create a `.env` file on the host that contains your variables.  Docker Compose will read these variables and apply them to your configuration.

Alternatively, or in conjunction with a `.env` file, you can set environment variables in your shell.  These variables will be applied the same way as those read from a `.env` file and actually take precedence.

Read more here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: Just to be clear, by host you mean the VPS where my sites are running? So in `/var/www/html/mysite.co.uk/` I'll have a `.env` file with the JSON where the keys match the environmental variables that my application is expecting?

Comment: Yes, the host where you execute `docker-compose up` will need the `.env` file in the current working directory. Those variables must match the variables declared in your compose file.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @swysocki, I'm getting an issue about whitespace! I've updated the question.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. I was using `var: value` instead of `var=value`.